# Website giving a different layout on chrome and firefox/ie with bootstrap 3

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, playframework-2.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

[This](http://privacymatters.herokuapp.com/dataController/ZA034620) is a page that I have and it has a different layout when in chrome and on firefox/ie. If this cannot be seen, I have an image for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYfQ9.png). The 3 panels inside the general purposes panel seem to not fill all the space correctly for ie and firefox. I am using the boostrap class "col-xs-4 col-sm-4" to divide each panel into 1/3 of my div but for firefox it is not rendering as it should be. If it's of any help, I am using the play framework and the template engine to render each page

Comment: I assume you're on a desktop, so shouldn't you use .col-lg-4 or .col-md-4?

Comment: I do not think that would make a difference with regard to this. I've used col-xs-4 and sm because I did not want the panels stacking up in smaller devices. I think that is the use of it. [bootstrap link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Comment: hmm, you're right.  Difficult to debug this from a screenshot though.  Can you paste it into jsFiddle?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/themakshter/ZVL9Z/) is a jsFiddle. However, I struggle to reproduce the same error on jsFiddle.

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/grcf17y77t2j9b6/test.zip) is a dropbox link to the materials I use to reproduce the error, if it is of any help. Not standard practice but it does show the error.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it when opening your jsFiddle in full page mode. It's much easier to debug now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to bootstrap.  There's an element in your css that interferes with the bootstrap layout.

```
.row {
    display: table;
}
```

If you remove that it's all good.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late reply, I had been busy to try this. While it seems to work, it does the opposite of what I would like. This makes the panels smaller, and is similar to the initial firefox view (panels not fully filling the parent panel width, while I want to achieve the chrome view (panels filling the parent panel fully).

Comment: I'm having a different Firefox view than the one you explain.  Here's the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/dsarosi/ZVL9Z/1/embedded/result/).